# cc.Label enabled stroke works but color does not change

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
 var label0 = cc.LabelTTF.create("test", "Arial",48 );
 label0.setColor(cc.c4f(0,0,0,255));
 this.addChild(label0, 1);
 label0.setPosition( cc.p(0, 80));
 label0.enableStroke(cc.c3b(100,10,0),3,true);
```

I try to change r,g,b value in label0.enableStroke(cc.c3b(100,10,0),3,true);

but it never change and display same color as label0.setColor(cc.c4f(0,0,0,255));

or

my usage has any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This..

```
CCLabelTTF*label=CCLabelTTF::create("My Text", "Thonburi", 15 );
int r,g,b;
r=100;
g=80;
b=255-r-g;
label->setColor(ccc3(r,g,b));
```